# Returning value for all rows with same key, based on a single value

Tags: sql

Is it possible to write a SQL script to create a table, which returns a single value from a table, based on an identifier for all connected rows?

For me to explain better, here's how the data looks like:

| ID | Value | QuestionID | QuestionText |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim Andersson | 1 | Name |
| 1 | Q894556 | 2 | Order Number |
| 1 | 21-03-2022 | 3 | Date |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would like to be able to pinpoint both the Name and the Order Number for 2 new columns like below, which should be returned for all rows connected to ID = 1:

| ID | Value | QuestionID | QuestionText | Name | Order Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim Andersson | 1 | Name | Jim Andersson | Q894556 |
| 1 | Q894556 | 2 | Order Number | Jim Andersson | Q894556 |
| 1 | 21-03-2022 | 3 | Date | Jim Andersson | Q894556 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: that is called unpivot, when look which you actual databse you are using, you will find many solutions

Comment: Given you're not changing granulation you could also join table on itself and just add the name and order number from second table.

Comment: I already found out that I could make a `SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [QuestionID] = 1` in a with statement to make a cte - but thought there might a another solution to this :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is joining table on itself given that the granulation of the output table should be the same as input table.

```
--create table for demonstration
create or replace TEMPORARY table test1.dummy (
     ID int,
     Value text,
     questionID int,
    questionText varchar);

--populate table with given data
INSERT INTO dummy values 
(1, 'Jim Andersson',1, 'Name'),
(1, 'Q894556',2,'Order Number'),
(1, '21-03-2022',3,'Date');
```

The idea here is that we just need to limit extra tables given the value you want to add. And since we're joining on itself we can do this using `INNER JOIN` since it's faster. However, if you're unsure that batch of records will all contain Name, Order Number and date you could also do this using `LEFT JOIN` and have those values empty.

```
SELECT d1.*, d2.value AS NAME, d3.value AS Order_number
FROM dummy d1
inner JOIN dummy d2 ON d1.id = d2.id AND d2.questionText = 'Name'
inner JOIN dummy d3 ON d1.id = d3.id AND d3.questionText = 'Order Number';
```

Now all you need to do is use this query or create new table and fill it with given query.